# Laravel - Letter appearing at the start of a view. Can't find why

Tags: laravel

So basically I have my route:

```
Route::get('/', array( 'as' => 'get-index', 'uses' => 'IndexController@getIndex' ))->before('guest');
```

I then have my controller:

```
<?php
class IndexController extends BaseController {

public function getIndex() {
    return "test";
}

}
```

When I run this, the page shows "ctest".
Note the letter C. I can't find this anywhere. It even shows when I point the controller to a view.

What is the queue like to showing a page. Where would this extra letter be coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mistyped that C in one of your views or even PHP files, I did that sometimes and it's really hard to find if we have lots of files, and, sometimes it's 'hidden' before a PHP block:

```
C<?php

class IndexController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex() {
        return "test";
    }

}
```

Comment: Found it! It was in my `filters.php` -.- So frustrating.